# JSR 303 set custom validator for cascade @valid

Tags: spring, hibernate, bean-validation, customvalidator

I want to validate a form object which is contained in another form object. I have something like this:

```
@Controller
public class FormController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void process(@ModelAttribute("form") @Valid FormObject formObject, 
                              BindingResult result) {
            ...
        @InitBinder("form")
        protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
             binder.setValidator(customFormValidator);
        }
    }

public class FormObject {
    @Valid
    private FormObject2 formObject2;
}

// This is the class that needs to be validated.
public class FormObject2 {
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;
}
}
```

The problem I'm having is that I want the object formObject2 to be validated by another custom validator (e.g. "customFormValidator2"), but I can't find how to register it. If I let it like this, the spring validator will validate the second form.

I have tried inside customFormValidator to validate the second form, but then the paths for the errors in the second form are not relative to the first form and I can't display the errors in the jsp page.

I have structured my form object like this, because I might need the second form inside other forms and by doing this I make it more modularized.

Is it possible what I'm trying to do? Do you have better suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom validator to validate `form Object2` like

```
 public void process(@ModelAttribute("form") @Valid FormObject formObject, 
                              BindingResult result) {
customFormValidator2.validate(formObject.getFormObject2(), result);  
}
```

And remove `@Valid` to remove JSR validation

```
public class FormObject {
 //   @Valid REMOVE THIS
     private FormObject2 formObject2;
}
```

Also you can use path attribute for nested classes  like

```
<form:input path="formObject2.any_property_name">
```

You can also use same path for errors without any problem.
Check this [link](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?34357-form-tag-s-path-attribute) for more details.

Comment: The problem is that I use this path <form:input path="formObject2.any_property_name">  but if I validate as you said, the errors are <form:errors path="any_property_name"> so not with the "formObject2" in front.

Comment: If I use @valid for FormObject2, the spring validator knows that the context is for formObject2.

Comment: I'd like to use with @valid my custom validator that uses the spring validator in its implementation and maybe I can have the correct path for the errors.. I'm not sure if it makes sense what I'm trying to say

Comment: @Marius: I am bit confused now. If you want to show validation error for some input then `<form:error>` path attribute should be same as the input. Why you are keeping then different? And as you mentioned you have written spring validator for `FormObject2` then why you want to use `@Valid` i.e. JSR validation ? Instead of that you should use the `.validate()` method, here you are mixing spring and JSR validation.